# Creating jar out of chosen classes with structure

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

Finally I've found a way to export single classes to jar file. My problem now is that it doesn't export structure but only single classes.
How can I export chosen classes and export it with the current directory structure? (so its in i.e /src/org/smth/cmp/asd/MyClass.class inside of jar)

Some things in IDEA are really counterintuitive in comparison how easy that was in `Eclipse` where selecting classes and simply using `Export...` function in context menu did what I'm talking about... Still like lots of its features though

Comment: Do you really want the `src` directory? Assuming your package is `org.smth.cmp.asd.MyClass`, if you place that inside the `src` directory within your JAR, your JAR will not work as a library or as an executable JAR. The root of the package must be at the root of the JAR. How are you exporting the single class into a JAR? Are you using a JAR artifact configuration? IDEA should copy the package (i.e. directory) structure.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why are you using idea to do this?

Comment: I'm doing it by function "add copy of" and "file" and choosing exact class in `Arifacts` option of `Project Structure`... Well, I don't need /src/ directory, my mistake, but I need directory structure anyway.

Comment: @EngineerDollery how else can I do it considering I've exact branch checked out in Idea?

Comment: If you can explain why you're doing this, I might be able to help more. As it stands, what you're doing is trivial if you use maven.

Comment: Well, I have an environment to which I upload certain jar including class which needs to be overriden (my jar name is already in classpath in the env.)